# Typing in "python3", but not "python", is recognized in powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell

After I type in "python3", it shows the python version as "3.8.5" but the version I have currently is python 3.10. What is going on?

Comment: Try `where python3` and compare the output against `where python` (or replacing python with the full path to your 3.10 interpreter)

Comment: @rv.kvetch Tried typing but its not giving me anything. It just gets ready for me to type the next command.

Comment: @MrMadagescar hmm, is it possible to post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should actively manage your python version. On Linux, you can use some orders to manage them,egs:

- if you want install python in the whole path.please install in `/opt/python/`
- if you want to add new candidate's python --version, you can use:`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python3 python3 /opt/python/3.8.5/bin/python3 80`

thanks for your reading!

Comment: But the best way is to search "how to manage python --version for Linux/windos" by Goole, which can help you the completion answers.

Answer (score -2):

I tried "py" instead of "python" or "python3" and its working. I guess I'll stick with "py" then.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).